# Continues variable not triggering while loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

Apologies if this is a repost. I am trying to write a while loop with a continue variable and if/else statement. My issue is that my `continue` variable is being ignored I cannot find the problem thus far. So far I have moved the `while continues == 'y'` condition into the else block now I am a bit flummoxed on why this var is being overlooked.

code:

```
def add_to_existing_file(data):
# data[0]-api response
# data[1]-city
# infile-file object returned from openFile()
# file_name- file name string. check filetype & report version.

continues = 'y' # set up continue variable
while continues == 'y':
    file_name = input("Enter File Path to file to be appended: ") # get file from user
    if file_name is False:
        print("Now Creating Excel File..") # create condition for no user response.
        return # if empty response exit function
    else:
        infile = appends.openFile(file_name)  # open file to work with. Returns file object.
        added_data = appends.journal_report_1_to_df(infile, file_name, data[0], data[1]) # append selected file to existing df
    continues = input("Do you want to append another file? Y or N").lower() # check if new file
    return added_data # return new df w/appended data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens on the last line. You're returning at the end of the first iteration, which exits the loop. This can be fixed by moving the return to the outer scope.

```py
def add_to_existing_file(data):
    # data[0]-api response
    # data[1]-city
    # infile-file object returned from openFile()
    # file_name- file name string. check filetype & report version.

    continues = 'y' # set up continue variable
    while continues == 'y':
        file_name = input("Enter File Path to file to be appended: ") # get file from user
        if file_name is False:
            print("Now Creating Excel File..") # create condition for no user response.
            return # if empty response exit function
        else:
            infile = appends.openFile(file_name)  # open file to work with. Returns file object.
            added_data = appends.journal_report_1_to_df(infile, file_name, data[0], data[1]) # append selected file to existing df
        continues = input("Do you want to append another file? Y or N").lower() # check if new file

    return added_data # return new df w/appended data
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you get the second return line (return added_data # return new df w/appended data) to have the same indentation as your while line. As a basic outline for a continue loop:

```
def function
   continues = 'y'
   while
      if :
      elif :
      else :
      print
      continue ?
   return
```